# mmenu dont work for undersites in a href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

i have a problem. the cms TYPO3 build ever the url in the a-Tag / href:
i use this mobile menu: [mmenu.frebsite.nl](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl)

here the frontend html:

```
<a class="mMenuButton" href="site2.html#menu"></a>
```

URL after click: `http://www.domain.com/site2.html#menu`

Template HTML - close/open Button:

```
<a class="mMenuButton" href="#menu"></a>
```

and here the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#menu").mmenu({
    header: {
        add: true,
        update: true,
        title: "Menü / Startseite",
    },
    offCanvas: {
        position: "top",
        zposition: "front"
    }
})  

});
```

the MMenu works fine on the home-site! How can i remove the "site2.html" ?
thanks

link: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/184

Comment: Any link starting with `#` is a bookmark link. It will always relate to the current page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answer but i cant del the href.
this is the HTML

```
<a class="mMenuButton" href="#menu"></a>
```

the href link may not work!
this js remove the link, but than jump the site on the home after click

```
$(".mMenuButton").attr("href", "#menu");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand your question in honesty, but if your question is as simple as how can you remove the site2.html or change, then just remove it from the href with another linked page or replace with # so it remains on the same page...Again the question makes little sense (to me at least) so not sure if this helps or not.

Answer (score 0):

So you dont have access to the html file which contains - `<a class="mMenuButton" href="site2.html#menu"></a>` is that right ? Just trying to get an understanding sorry.

Answer (score 0):

mh no, the HTML is only this:

```
<a class="mMenuButton" href="#menu"></a>
```

an the TYPO3 make this:

```
<a class="mMenuButton" href="site2.html#menu"></a>
```